# Trouble with advance searching using android app

Tags: bug, search, android-app

I want to filter my answer and hence tried `user:66803 is:answer`  on [Unix & Linux](http://linux.stackexchange.com) using android app but it displays nothing! You can also try searching/filtering such. So, Why does it not working?

Comment: I typed `user:66803 is:answer` into the Search bar of both the web and iOS app and it worked fine for both.  Would you be able to include a screenshot doing the same with the Android app, please?

Comment: The android app is VERY limited, and can search only questions. Since SE stopped working on the app, I don't expect this to ever be "fixed". /cc @Poly